# Convert "current time" to "time in minutes since 00:00" calculation help

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

I haven't used NSDate that much, so I'd like some help with a calculation I am doing.

I have an integer that has my store's closing hour in minutes since midnight. Basically, my store closes at 5.00PM, which gives me the integer 1020.

So right now it's 10.45PM or 22.45. Integer since 00:00 is 1365, and from this I can say

```
if (storeHour < currentTime) {
      // closed!
}
```

However, I don't know how I get from "22.45" that I have from NSDate to converting it to an integer representing time since 00:00. Is there something in NSDate that can help me with that?

Thx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do recommend using an `NSDate` object to store the time the store closes instead of using your own custom integer format.  It's unfortunate that `NSDate` represents both date and time of date.

In any case, you can check [`NSDateComponents`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSDateComponents).  You can have a utilities method like:

```
int minutesSinceMidnight:(NSDate *)date
{
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
        initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    unsigned unitFlags =  NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:date];

    return 60 * [components hour] + [components minute];    
}
```

Comment: If you make this a category method of NSDate you would not need to pass the date as a parameter. Just make sure to prefix the category's method name with your own name space.

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 5**
This for exemple gives you the current number of minutes since midnight

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let now = Date()

print(getMinutesSinceMidnight())

func getMinutesSinceMidnight() -> Int {
        return (calendar.component(.hour, from: now) * 60 + calendar.component(.minute, from: now))
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

A swift version of what @notnoop has replied:

```
func minutesSinceMidnight(start : NSDate) -> Int {

    let units : NSCalendarUnit = [.Hour, .Minute]
    let components = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(units, fromDate: start)
    return 60 * components.hour + components.minute
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have another `NSDate` which is set to midnight, then you can use the `timeIntervalSinceDate` method of the NSDate object to get an `NSTimeInterval` back with the difference between the two. Alternatively, if you're always wanting to compare midnight with the current time, you could call the `timeIntervalSinceNow` method on the midnight NSDate and you'd get an `NSTimeInterval` back (albeit negative) with the difference between midnight and the current time.

`NSTimeInterval` is defined as a `double` by the standard which holds a number of seconds (and any fractional seconds).

Answer (score 1):

This is a contemporary way without any extra math.

**Objective-C**

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *midnight = [calendar startOfDayForDate:[NSDate date]];
NSInteger minutesSinceMidnight = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitMinute fromDate:midnight toDate:[NSDate date] options:0].minute;
```

---

**Swift 3+** as `Date` extension

```
extension Date {
    func minutesSinceMidnight() -> Int {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let midnight = calendar.startOfDay(for: self)
        return calendar.dateComponents([.minute], from: midnight, to: self).minute!
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
print(Date().minutesSinceMidnight())
```